# BASH output from grep

Tags: bash, grep, stdout

I am relatively new to bash and I am testing my code for the first case.

```
counter=1
for file in not_processed/*.txt; do
  if [ $counter -le 1 ]; then
    grep -v '2018-07' $file > bis.txt;
    counter=$(($counter+1));
  fi;
done
```

I want to subtract all the lines containing '2018-07' from my file. The new file needs to be named $file_bis.txt.

Thanks

Comment: You may use ```sed``` command in linux for this purpose

Comment: @JPV, adding two sample files along with expected output and file name would help here.. `grep -v` matches with your text `subtract` but you have accepted an answer that does opposite.. also, not sure why you are using `counter` in your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` or `awk` it's much easier and faster to process complex files.

```
sed -n '/2018-07/p' not_processed/*.txt
```

then you get the output in your console. If you want you can pipe the output to a new file.

```
sed -n '/2018-07/p' not_processed/*.txt >> out.txt
```

Comment: But I would like to pipie into different files.

Comment: That was not in your example. you pipe all to the same file and overwrite it.

Comment: `easier and faster` depends on use case.. `grep` would be faster here as well as more compact..  `grep '2018-07'`

Comment: That was my mistake. But could you please tell me
?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood why you are using a counter and `if` condition for this simple requirement. Use below script which will fulfill you requirement:-

```
#first store all the files in a variable
files=$(ls /your/path/*.txt)
# now use a for loop
for file in $files;
do
  grep '2018-07' $file >> bis.txt
done
```

Better avoid for loop here as below single line is suffice

```
grep -h '2018-07' /your/path/*.txt >  bis.txt
```

Comment: don't use ls output, it would not work if file name contains space, newline, etc... no need to save result in variable, when you can use `for file in /your/path/*.txt` reliably.. and no need for loop when you can do `grep '2018-07' /your/path/*.txt` (unless there are too many files)

Comment: @Sundeep, you are very true. I have just modified his `for loop`. I have modified my answer with your suggestion. Thanks for your comment and advice.

Comment: `grep xxx file1 file2` will put "file1:" or "file2:" at the start of matching lines, while `grep xxx file1` won't, by default. Use the `-H` option to force the name to be added to output lines, or `-h` to suppress the name.

Comment: @simon3270, thanks for your advice I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do it on all files in not_processed/*.txt

```
for file in not_processed/*.txt
do
  grep -v '2018-07' $file > "$file"_bis.txt
done
```

And this is to do it only on the first 2 files in not_processed/*.txt

```
for file in $(ls not_processed/*.txt|head -2)
do
  grep -v '2018-07' $file > "$file"_bis.txt
done
```

Don't forget to add "" on $file, because otherwise bash considers $file_bis as a new variable, which has no assigned value.